# Broken network connection after Docker install/uninstall on Linux Mint 20.1 / Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, networking, linux-mint

I recently installed, then uninstalled Docker, using `sudo apt install docker.io`, restarting, then `sudo apt remove docker.io` on Linux Mint 20.1.

Since then (actually after the install), my network connection fails. I then used Timeshift on Linux Mint to restore my system to before the Docker install, but still the connection doesn't work: "Activation of network connection failed" from the Network popup window.

I have read some posts about others who have lost network connection after Docker installed, but all the advice I have read is how to fix it with Docker installed, but I have it removed now, and want to get my network connection working.

My `systemd-resolve --status` output:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa     
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa 
                      corp                
                      d.f.ip6.arpa        
                      home                
                      internal            
                      intranet            
                      lan                 
                      local               
                      private             
                      test                
Link 2 (enp4s0)
      Current Scopes: none
DefaultRoute setting: no  
       LLMNR setting: yes 
MulticastDNS setting: no  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no  
      DNSSEC setting: no  
    DNSSEC supported: no
```

My `ifconfig` output:

```
$ ifconfig 
enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b4:2e:99:94:68:10  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 4916  bytes 297761 (297.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 4916  bytes 297761 (297.7 KB)
```

Any tips for what I can run to try debug this?

Answer (score 2):

Docker and networking are pretty unpredictable and as I do it for work on Linux mint, my experience is that docker and networking are flaky and could suddenly stop working seemingly without cause. But what you're seeing is a step too far. Because network issues, especially in Linux, are so hard with that info to debug I can't really offer any specific help, but I'll go ahead and rattle off the first giant handful of things I'd try or think about. At least that stuff would be the stuff I'd be googling about:

- check the `etc/hosts` file, `etc/hosts.allow`, `etc/hosts.deny`, `etc/resolv.conf`.
- Restart all the network services ex) service networking restart
- service network-manager restart
- ifconfig
- nslookup google.com
- Could it be a router/modem/ISP issue?

Comment: That answer and many others online are about people who have lost network connectivity inside a Docker container. The problem I'm having is with network connectivity outside Docker. I don't need Docker on my system and have uninstalled it, but still there is no network connectivity on my system. Unfortunately, solutions involving taking actions inside Docker don't seem to apply.

Comment: Oh. Duh. I really need to read better. So I've experienced this once before in Linux Mint, but can't remember the fix. Well I threw out some ideas. I think it should lead you in the right direction

Comment: Great list! I think I had not the same issue as in the question but network issues and your list of things to check is a great general advice and solved it anyhow.